# Python: update/delete before insert

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

Everytime I am executing my python (sql) code it just keeps adding more and more data to my table more and more rows its just keeps growing, somehow i need to Update it or Delete before INSERT'ing data to table, but i dont know how.

Here is my code:

```
import MySQLdb
from calculationmethod import Method
class dbcclib(Method):

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of the object."""
    return "Density matrix of" % (self.data)

def __repr__(self):
    """Return a representation of the object."""
    return 'Density matrix("%s")' % (self.data)
def push(self):
    # Open database connection
    dbhost1 = raw_input("Enter databse host: ")
    dbport = int(raw_input("Enter databse port: "))
    dbuser = raw_input("Enter dabase user: ")
    dbpass = raw_input("Enter databse password: ")
    dbname = raw_input("Enter database: ")

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host = dbhost1,port = dbport,user = dbuser,passwd = dbpass , db = dbname)

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cur = db.cursor()

    # Create table as per requirement
    self.data.vibstate
    cur.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        cord
        (x, y, z)
        VALUES
            (%s, %s, %s)
    """, self.data.vibstate)
    db.commit()
    # disconnect from server
    db.close()
    print "Baigta"
```

I will define now my "MESS", in this example i have 2D array lets say its like this :

```
a = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
```

and now then i am INSERT'ing it couple of times into my table : it looks like that:

```
columns     x y z
            1 2 3
            3 2 1
            1 2 3
            3 2 1
```

Its duplicating everytime. Everytime i execute it it adds more and more rows. So i need to get rid off of that duplication.

Comment: what is your condition to delete? do you need to remove all data every time app start?

Comment: i dont know i just want to get rid off that mess , so i dont know is it better to delete evrything and then write again or to check and update, thats why i am asking :)

Comment: Can you define the "MESS" that you want to get rid off in your question?  So that we can suggest you something....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get rid of duplicate data, you should use PK and UPSERT (Insert if not exist, else update). if you need clean db each time, just run **truncate** command before insert.
In Mysql use following structure:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

If you don't want to modify and just need to get rid of duplicate user INSERT IGNORE instead.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3);
```

Remember to create unique constrains for all 3 fields.

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE INDEX unq (a, b, c)
```

Comment: UPSERT sounds ok for this situation

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            x = VALUES(x),
            y = VALUES(y),
            z = VALUES(z);

Comment: Use Insert IGNORE INTO table(a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3);, you still need to define PK. or unique constraint

Comment: still duplicate valuse :(

Comment: CREATE TABLE `table` (a int,b int,c int);ALTER TABLE `table` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unq` (`a`, `b`, `c`);INSERT INTO `table` (a,b,c) values(1,2,3);INSERT INTO `table` (a,b,c) values(1,2,3); -- only one time added!